# Is there software that aids street by street range vs. range analysis of hand history?

Tags: texas-hold-em, range

Is there software that allows you to view a hand history such that you are able to populate each players range, and how you think that range changes from street to street?

I'm aware of, i.e., Flopzilla, but that only allows you to see how a flop hits one range. What I'm looking for is more a street by street, range vs. range analyzer that packages your analysis for a hand (so you can share that analysis with other people, etc).

Comment: Question is not clear to me.

Comment: I think you're looking for HoldemResources Calculator. You can assign ranges street by street I believe and it even tells you how their ranges should look if they're playing GTO. Not sure about the sharing feature.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of pokerstove, it's free software that could work for this purpose. Only problem is you would have to manually input all of the data yourself (i.e. it does not work with online hand histories to my knowledge). just input the cards that came on each street and the range that you think that your opponent (or you) have and it will give you percentages by using simulation.